# cannot install mysql using npm in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have tried following commands,mysql module does not get added to node_module folder,also the code using mysql throw an error.

```
   Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.8.3 (ia32) and NPM

C:\Users\Work>npm install mysql
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hashish/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hashish/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
mysql@0.9.6 node_modules\mysql
└── hashish@0.0.4 (traverse@0.6.3)

C:\Users\Work>npm install mysql@2.0.0-alpha3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql/2.0.0-alpha3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql/2.0.0-alpha3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
mysql@2.0.0-alpha3 node_modules\mysql
└── require-all@0.0.3

C:\Users\Work>node D:\nodejs\sqlwrite.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\sqlwrite.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)

C:\Users\Work>
```

i have entered the commands as shown on github.

Comment: You should add path to system variable. i.e; path where you installed mysql mudule.

Comment: Which OS you are using ?

Comment: Windows 7(64bit)-Ultimate.
the mysql module is not getting added in node_module folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the path (where node modules are installed) to system variable. Or navigate to default system path for NodeJS modules and install NodeJS modules. This is path for my system:

`C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Comment: I copied the module from 'C:\Users\Work\node_modules\mysql' where it got installed to the nodejs folder in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules'.
Still same error.

Comment: See if that path is included in system variable `Path` ?

Comment: >C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\  
is included in system variable Path.

Comment: Thankyou i needed to run the node.js command prompt as administrator,that solved the problem